# How do you implement client SSO on sitecore cross domain?

Tags: sitecore, single-sign-on

Everything I searched for returns info about internal user SSO, not client facing websites.

I need an SSO implimentation that works with sitecore's asp.net membership api or has it's own sitecore security provider to enable users who log in to publicfacingwebsite1.com to be able to be logged in to publicfacingwebsite2.com and logging out of one will log out of the other.  I would prefer sitecore's asp.net membership provider as that will probably have the least upgrade implications in the future.

The domains are different top level domains.  The websites are separate sites on the same sitecore instance.

I also need the side ability to impersonate a user (log in as the user) from an admin user, but once I have the main implementation, I'm sure I can find a method for the impersonation.

Regards

Comment: Can you run both sites in the same Sitecore instance? Are both sites running Sitecore, or just one of them?

Comment: Modified question to answer site details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a third party framework for the SSO part. For instance [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer)

[Here is a good introduction on how to use it together with Sitecore](https://cprakash.com/2015/12/30/sitecore-extranet-authentication-with-openidconnect/)

In regards to the membership provider and the profile data, if you are thinking upgradeability, I am not sure it will be so, if you use the native membership provider. Sitecore will most likely switch to ASP.Net Identity in the near future. The ASP.NET Identity is supported in IdentityServer3, so you might obtain a shared user profile by using IdentityServer for the profile as well. But this is all guessing the future.

If you want to use the membership provider and the standard Sitecore profile provider, I am sure you can customize the implicit flow to map the Identity to a Sitecore user.